# Deploy to heroku fails to deploy "no module dateutil.parser" when it's included in requirements.txt

Tags: django, heroku, python-dateutil

I'm a django newby and this is my first question posted to StackOverflow:

I've successfully deployed a couple of apps to heroku over the past month but when I added a module fixed2csv that imports dateutil.parser, heroku fails to find the module even though it's in the requirements.txt file.

Here's a snippet from heroku's deploy message...

> ```
>    Downloading/unpacking python-dateutil==2.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 20))
>      Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip_build_u20147/python-dateutil/setup.py) egg_info for
> ```
>
> package python-dateutil
>
> ```
>    Downloading/unpacking fixed2csv==0.2.3 (from -r requirements.txt (line 21))
>      Downloading fixed2csv-0.2.3.tar.gz
>      Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip_build_u20147/fixed2csv/setup.py) egg_info for package
> ```
>
> fixed2csv
>              Traceback (most recent call last):
>                File "", line 17, in 
>                File "/tmp/pip_build_u20147/fixed2csv/setup.py", line 7, in 
>                  import fixed2csv
>                File "fixed2csv.py", line 10, in 
>                  import dateutil.parser
>              ImportError: No module named dateutil.parser
>              Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
>              Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> ```
>      File "<string>", line 17, in <module>
>
>      File "/tmp/pip_build_u20147/fixed2csv/setup.py", line 7, in <module>
>
>        import fixed2csv
>
>      File "fixed2csv.py", line 10, in <module>
>
>        import dateutil.parser
>
>    ImportError: No module named dateutil.parser
>
>    ----------------------------------------
>    Cleaning up...
>    Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_u20147/fixed2csv
>    Storing debug log for failure in /app/.pip/pip.log
> ```
>
> !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app

Everything works fine in my virtualenv when I installed python-dateutil so I'm not sure where to go from here.

Update:
I worked around it by not using the module that required python-dateutil.  I would be interested to know how to get Heroku to recognize python-dateutil though because it's way nicer to use than messing around with strptime format strings.

Comment: It looks like `fixed2csv` depends on `dateutil`, so make sure `dateutil` comes _before_ `fixed2csv` in the `requirements.txt` file

Comment: python-dateutil==2.2 is before fixed2csv. In the deploy message above you can see that it is downloading and unpacking dateutil ahead of fixed2csv.  I've tried moving dateutil to the top of the requirements.txt file and also just above fixed2csv.  It didn't make a difference.

Comment: were you able to solve this?